# Init object in -(void) method

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two classes for view controller, `classA` and `classB` that is subclass of `classA`.

In the `classA`, I write a method `startAnimation` that allow to display view like `ActivityIndicator`;

I tried to use `-(void)startAnimation` in `classB` by calling `[self startAnimation]`, it did not work well but changing to `-(BOOL)startAnimation` works well. I haven't understood yet. Please explain for me:

```
-(BOOL)startAnimation{
     __block bool a = NO;
    _displayViewForActivityIndicator = [[ProcessingIndicationView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-self.view.frame.size.width, -self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    [self.view addSubview:_displayViewForActivityIndicator];
    LogDebug(@"Start the method");
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState
                 animations:^{
                     //end position:
                     _displayViewForActivityIndicator.frame = self.view.frame;
                 }
    completion:^(BOOL finished) {
         if (finished) {
             LogDebug(@"Finish animation");
         }
         a = YES;
    }];
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Why do you mean by "not working well"? Is the animation jerky, things didn't move or the code refused to compile?

Comment: things didn't move, thanks @ZoffDino. I think that object _displayViewForActivityIndicator can't be referenced?